# mysql: result counting data as encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption, count

i have a problem during count data use this query:

```
   SELECT A.*, 
          COUNT( B.Serial_number ) AS Qty_insp, 
          CONCAT(ROUND(A.`Reject_qty`/ COUNT(B.Serial_number)*100, 2),'%') AS NG_Ratio
     FROM oqc_defect A
LEFT JOIN inspection_report B ON A.Model = B.Model
                             AND A.Line = B.Line
 GROUP BY A.Problem_date
```

i get result as encryption code for NG_Ratio like : 3532e......
why its happen, how to resolve this problem?

### Edit

```
Reject_qty                   Qty_insp                   NG_Ratio
2                             20                           10%
```

Comment: What are the `a.reject_qty` and `COUNT(B.Serial_number)` values when you get the exponential value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CONCAT(CAST(ROUND(A.`Reject_qty`/ COUNT(B.Serial_number)*100, 2) AS CHAR),'%') AS NG_Ratio
```

Answer (score 0):

Why it's happening: probably it's outputting exponential formatted numbers, like `3532e-2` being equivalent to `35.32`.

It's a little hard to tell since you cut off the output at the `e`, just as it was getting interesting :-)

I think [`cast() with decimal format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) may be able to turn that into the desired format or, alternatively, try:

```
ROUND (A.`Reject_qty` * 100) / COUNT (B.Serial_number), 2)
```

(I haven't tested this, it may not work).

Comment: how to make it can show result as real answer? not as code. is that something wrong or any query that i must change?

Comment: ya..i have tried this way before. but i need to add "%" in the result, so i use CONCAT. but after use it the result show as code.any idea?

Comment: I know how to do it with DB2 so you may want to try the equivalent for MySQL: cast it to decimal(?,2) then cast that to char then just add the `%`. Something like `cast(cast(val as decimal(10,2)) as char) | '%'` (may need trimming).